# What would be $P(f(A) \leq x) $ for a function $f$ and random number $A \in [0,1]$?

Tags: probability

Say that we generate a random number $A \in [0,1]$. We then square that number and graph the probability $P$ of the result being $\leq x$ (a constant).

A small simulation gives us some approximate points:
[image]

But how to find of which function $g(x)$, if all points were plotted, that would be a graph of?

More generally, what is the formula for $y = g(x) = P(f(A) \leq x)$ for any function $f$?

Comment: What is $x$ in your first line? Is it $a^2$?

Comment: Edited. It's an arbitrary constant

Comment: Is $A$ generated uniformly ?

Comment: Yes, there is the same chance that $A$ is any number from 0 to 1. It'd be alright to assume that $f$ is invertible

Answer (score 0):

Since you refer to $A$ being a "random" number in $[0, 1]$, I'll assume that you mean it's uniformly generated. Your simulation seems to have a problem somewhere, because it didn't quite do what you described.

For a tangible example, let $x = 0.25$. Note that $\mathbb P(A^2 < 0.25) = \mathbb P(A < \sqrt{0.25}) = \mathbb P (A < 0.5) \color{red}= 0.5. $ (The red equality is where we use the uniformity of $A$.) And yet, on your graph it appears that $f(0.25) \approx 0.13$ or so.

The above discussion does suggest how to consider the general formula, though -- if your function $f$ is invertible on $[0,1]$, then $\mathbb P(f(A) < x) = \mathbb P (A < f^{-1}(x)) = f^{-1}(x)$ since $A$ is uniformly distributed.

Comment: Were you able to find the apparent bug in your simulation code?